# xargs -r0 vs xargs -0

Tags: xargs

I have seen examples on the web of `xargs` with the argument `-r0`. What does this argument mean? My man pages don't show any entries for -`r0` nor do most man pages I have seen (e.g. http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`-r0` is two flags. It is `-r` and it is `-0`.

From the man page of the GNU implementation of `xargs`¹:

> -r
> If the standard input does not contain any nonblanks, do not run the command.
> Normally, the command is run once  even if there is no input.  This option is a
> GNU extension.
>
> -0
> Input items are terminated by a null character instead of by whitespace, and
> the quotes and backslash are not  special (every  character  is  taken
> literally).   Disables the end of file string, which is treated like any other
> argument. Useful when input items might contain white space, quote marks, or
> backslashes.  The GNU find -print0 option  produces input suitable for this
> mode.

---

<sup>¹ Both the `-r` and `-0` options originate in the GNU implementation of `xargs`. `-0` is now commonly found in many other implementations, `-r` less so, but that's likely going to change as [both will be included in Issue 8 of the POSIX specification](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=243#c6110).</sup>

Comment: I missed it too. Duh it's 2 switches. I didn't even think of that, thanks Evan!