# Why is `-r` seemingly ignored when used with `-0` in GNU xargs?

Tags: xargs, gnu

The regular case with linefeeds, `xargs` calls `printf` and something is printed:

```
>>printf "foo\n" | xargs -r printf "->%s\n"
->foo
>>
```

With an empty input instead, `-r` makes `xargs` not call the command at all:

```
>>printf "\n" | xargs -r printf "->%s\n"
>>
```

Using nulls instead of line feeds, everything is the same if there is an input to `xargs`:

```
>>printf "foo\0" | xargs -r -0 printf "->%s\n"
->foo
>>
```

But if there is no input, something is printed anyway:

```
>>printf "\0" | xargs -r -0 printf "->%s\n"
->
>>
```

So, either

- I'm missing something (what?)
- There is some good reason to ignore `-r` when used with `-0` (but which)?
- There is a bug in my `xargs` (findutils 4.6.0.225-235f) but it's hard to decide:

  - I find the same behavior in two other instances (a 4.7.0-git on Ubuntu 16.04 and another 4.6.0 on Windows),
  - I can't believe this kind of thing could slip thru regression tests.
  - On the other hand [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83709/xargs-r0-vs-xargs-0) implies that it could have worked in the past

So, what is the true expected behavior of `xargs`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`xargs -r cmd` skips running `cmd` without arguments.

With `-0`, one argument is created for each NUL-delimited record on input

```
printf '\0' | xargs -r0 cmd
```

You're feeding one empty record, so `cmd` is called with one empty argument (and with `printf '\0\0'`, that would be 2 empty records, etc).

With:

```
printf '' | xargs -r0 cmd
```

You're feeding no record, so `cmd` is not run.

With:

```
printf '' | xargs -0 cmd
```

You're still not feeding any record, but because `-r` is not provided, `cmd` is still called once without argument.

Without `-0`, `xargs` expects a very special input format, it's not a simple delimited list like with `xargs -0` or `xargs -d '\n'`

To feed one empty argument, you need something like:

```
printf '""\n' | xargs -r cmd
printf "''\n" | xargs -r cmd
```

or for that matters:

```
printf '\n\n \t\t "" \n\n \t\n' | xargs -r cmd
```

`printf -- '-%s\n'` is not the best choice of command to test that as it gives the same output when passed no argument as when passed one empty argument.

A better one could be:

```
$ printf '\n\n \t\t "" \n\n \t\n' | xargs -r zsh -c 'PS4=Got; set -x; : "$@"' zsh
Got: ''
$ printf '\n\n \t\t \n\n \t\n' | xargs zsh -c 'PS4=Got; set -x; : "$@"' zsh
Got:
$ printf '\t\n\n' | xargs -rd '\n' zsh -c 'PS4=Got; set -x; : "$@"' zsh
Got: $'\t' ''
```

Or:

```
$ printf '\t\n\0\0' | xargs -0 zsh -c 'print -rl $#: " - ${(q+)^@}"' zsh
2:
 - $'\t\n'
 - ''
```